# How to find count of a div containing specific value in React, Jest and Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am looking for a solution using React, Jest and Enzyme. I am a newbie to these technologies.

I could get a few simple tests to run. Now here is what I want to test:

```
<div className="trow">
            <div className="tcolid" >101</div>
            <div className="tcolname">Joe</div>
            <div className="tcolgender">M</div>
          </div>

          <div className="trow">
            <div className="tcolid" >102</div>
            <div className="tcolname">Abc</div>
            <div className="tcolgender">F</div>
          </div>

          <div className="trow">
            <div className="tcolid" >103</div>
            <div className="tcolname">Xyz</div>
            <div className="tcolgender">F</div>
          </div>
          ...
          ...
```

My React component consumes data from a rest api. The API can return multiple records male and/or female. My requirement is to  ensure only a single male employee to be rendered in UI. I have that achieved - not a problem.

When I am writing tests using Jest and Enzyme I want to check that when I render I only render a single html element having a value 'M'.

Here is what I have tried - Jest / Enzyme does not like it.

```
expect (wrapper.find("div.tcolgender").text()).toEqual("M").toHaveLength(1);
```

This does not work. I looked at the Enzyme API - dont find any 'count' or similar such method. Note - this is a 'full' render and not a 'shallow' render.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can write your selector to match all of the `div`s with `M` contents

```
const children = wrapper.find('div.tcolgender[children="M"]')
```

and assert the children will have length of one

```
expect(children).toHaveLength(1);
```

[working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-shirley-egbhd)